# Close Button on VS11 Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I try to create an Application on Windows 8 with VS 11 with C#, And I need to a Button in my App that when people Click on this button , my App going to Close.

But I can't find any Exit or Close function to add, to my Click Event.

how can I make this button? or what is your proposal to solving this Problem?

Comment: You're missing the whole point of the Metro UI. If the apps were meant to be closed in the traditional way, they would have included a close button. The design team didn't just forget it.

Comment: Closing windows is just an old fashioned user burden, particularly unnecessary in a presentation model that shows one window at a time.  I already run Win7 with every window maximized and rarely close them.  Really only when I run out of taskbar button space.  Metro made it a design feature.  You *do* have to cope with the OS unceremoniously terminating your program.  Blissfully retiring the SAVE button as well, that was about time too.

Comment: Windows apps have no windows. ∴No window close button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about certification - e.g. you want a close button in your own debug build to help you with testing - you can call Application.Current.Exit()

Answer (score 8):

**You shouldn't close your app.**

*This is one of the concepts of Metro apps.The user switches to a different task and the 
**Process Lifetime Management** aspects kick in, first suspending your application and then later, if needed, terminating it.
Don't close the application's window: let the user know that there is no information currently available and then let them switch away, close, or wait as they'd prefer*.

Took from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/516e3443-ce5b-4e7d-8198-064655e4608e)

Answer (score 4):

You must not implement Close Button.

If you do so, your app will be not able to sell in the store. See "[Certification requirements for Windows apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083)".

> 3.6 Your app must use the mechanisms provided by the system for those features that have them
>  
>   (snip)
>   Your app must neither programmatically close nor offer UI affordances to close it.

Answer (score 2):

You want this?
App.Current.Exit();

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It worked

```
App.Current.Terminate();
```