# How can a Windows Store App close itself?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-store-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close Button on VS11 Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446805/close-button-on-vs11-apps)

How can a Windows Store app close itself in code (C# but JS could be helpful too)?

Comment: @Tawnos Yep, that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment reposted as answer:
Duplicate of this question: [Close Button on VS11 Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446805/close-button-on-vs11-apps)

The short of it: you shouldn't have a close button if you are actually making a Windows Store app (it won't be certified), but you can use `Application.Current.Close()` if you need a button for debug close.